# Java EE, Problème in the previous button of browser

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsf, primefaces

I have a problem I have met many times in my web application.
I use the following technologies: Spring IOC, JSF 2 Primefaces, hibernate.

When I navigate between the pages of my application, and I change the data (Edit, Delete, Add) and I click in the previous boutton browser, the data pages are not refreshed.
For example:
I have two pages, the first contains a table of employees, when I click on an employee I redirect me to a second page to change the data of the latter. when I change the data and I click on the previous boutton browser, I found that the employee's data is not changed, knowing that they have been modified in the database.

if someone can help me ...

Comment: Well you should not transfer to second for getting data. Check this out. http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml

Comment: yes i know that (Spring, primefaces...) is not a source of problem, but i mentioned it for you know the technology that i use